# Under what conditions of $A,B$ we have $\det (A + \lambda B)$ is uniformly $0$ for all $\lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Assume $A,B$ are real-value symmetric matrix (maybe redundant condition) and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. This question comes from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/225780/739926), but the answerer doesn't give the condition.

Comment: Do you want conditions under which $det(A+\lambda B)=0$ for all $\lambda$?

Comment: Right, for all $\lambda$.

Comment: One thing that works is if $A$ is singular, and $B$ is a scalar multiple of $B$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Presumably you mean $B$ is a scalar multiple of $A$

Comment: @wz0919 One condition you might find useful: if there is a vector $x \neq 0$ for which $Ax = 0$ and $Bx = 0$ (or for which $A^Tx = 0$ and $B^Tx = 0$), then the determinant is uniformly zero.

Comment: @Ben, thanks, I should be more careful.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Your (sufficient) condition is $\mathcal{N}(A) \cap \mathcal{N}(B) \ne \{0\}$, right? Another sufficient condition is $\mathcal{R}(A) \cup \mathcal{R}(B) \ne \mathbb{R}^n$, right?